# Pig Latin Algorithm - .push() is not a Function

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing an algorithm for Free Code Camp. The algorithm wants me to convert text to pig latin. However, the issue I'm having isn't related to Pig Latin but rather something wrong in my code. Here's the error I'm getting:

`stringArray.push('a', 'y');`

and here's my code:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
    var consonantCluster = [];
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    var stringArray = str.split('');

    //If stringArray begins with a vowel, add 'way' to the end
    if (vowels.indexOf(stringArray[0]) === 0) {
        stringArray.push('w', 'a', 'y');
        stringArray = stringArray.join('');
        str = stringArray;
        console.log(str);
    }

    //If stringArray begins with consonant (or cluster), move to end of the stringArray and add 'ay'
    //Get all consonants up until first vowel
    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(stringArray[i]) == -1) {
            consonantCluster.push(stringArray[i]);
            stringArray.push(stringArray[i]);
        } else {
            stringArray.push('a', 'y');
            stringArray.splice(0, consonantCluster.length);
            stringArray = stringArray.join('');
            str = stringArray;
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(str);
    return str;
}

translatePigLatin("apple");
```

My code returns the expected result, but it's still reporting an error. Would anyone be able to help out? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to return inside the `if` statement. Then `stringArray = stringArray.join('')` makes `stringArray` a string, which don't have `push`.

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
    var consonantCluster = [];
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    var stringArray = str.split('');
    if (vowels.indexOf(stringArray[0]) === 0) {
        stringArray.push('w', 'a', 'y');
        stringArray = stringArray.join('');
        return stringArray; // <-- exit function
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(stringArray[i]) == -1) {
            consonantCluster.push(stringArray[i]);
            stringArray.push(stringArray[i]);
        } else {
            stringArray.push('a', 'y');
            stringArray.splice(0, consonantCluster.length);
            stringArray = stringArray.join('');
            str = stringArray;
            break;
        }
    }
    return str; // <-- exit function
}
translatePigLatin("apple");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you are calling the method `push` on some object that does not have the method `push`, thus the error

> `.push()` is not a function

Since you have many different branches in your code, this may not be a full encompassing error, but most likely, the method `.join` gets executed on `stringArray`...thus `stringArray` is no longer an array and just a string. `String` does not have a method called `push`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join